# Generic SwiftUI Component cannot infer Hashable for CustomStringConvertible

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a generic type, that accepts anything that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` and then iterates over those items.

Here is an example that distils down that problem:

```swift
public struct Test<ItemType: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable>: View {
    var items: [ItemType]

    public var body: some View {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text("test")
        }
    }

}
let items: [String] = ["a", "b"]
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: Test(items: items))
```

So I get an error
`Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'ItemType' conform to 'Hashable'`

and
`Generic parameter 'Hashable' could not be inferred`

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax issue:

```
public struct Test<ItemType: CustomStringConvertible & Hashable>: View {   // <<: here!
    var items: [ItemType]

    public var body: some View {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text("test")
        }
    }

}
```